# Stanford CorenNLP Phrase POS tags and lemmatization explanation

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I have this result during lemmatization of the phrase:

> Gathered requirements

Using the [corenlp online tool](http://corenlp.run/), POS-tagging and lemmatization of this phrase results in:

[image]

For some reason "Gathered" is given a POS-tag of "JJ" ("adjective"), which presumably results in the lemma being "gathered" rather than "gather".

If the input phrase is `gathered requirements` (i.e. lower-cased), then the POS tag is correctly identified as a verb, and the lemmatization result is what I expected:

[image]

Why is CoreNLP identifying `Gathered` as an adjective rather than a verb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system checks the probability of POS tag that most happened for the word "Gathered" when you write "Gathered requirments". Only some kind of words such as named-entities, start of sentence, etc. start with a capital letter. The general reason that "Gathered" is more likely to be JJ when you start it with a capital letter is that it was mostly used as adjective not verb in start of sentence.

Comment: As far as I know `gather` and its past tense `gathered` are verbs. I can't think of any english sentence in which `gather` or `gathered` is an adjective. Can you?

Comment: "Gathered documents were held in office", which gathered is an adjective for requirments.

Comment: In the phrase "Gathered documents were held in the office", `Gathered` is a past participle verb used as an adjective, and Stanford NLP identifies it as such (VBN rather than JJ, and the lemma is still `gather`). So, I'm still not seeing any examples with Gathered that Stanford NLP would identify as JJ.

Comment: Yes you are right CoreNLP identifies all past participle verbs that are used as adjectives as VBN. The only counterexample is the one you found. The only reason I can think of know is that there is one "Gathered requirements"   tagged as "JJ NNS" in the corpus that coreNLP is trained with  .

Comment: Gathered as adjective is mentioned at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gathered). In this case I think CorenNLP is just wrong.

Comment: Interesting -- where did you find the information about the `JJ NNS` tag in the training corpus? Would be interested in a link...

Comment: This is one of the papers that CoreNLP pos tagger is based on : http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/papers/emnlp2000.pdf . In the abstract it is mentioned that penn treebank is used for evaluation and the system has a accuracy of 96.86% on penn treebank and 86.91% on unseen previous words. So in your case two things might have happened. One is that as I said there is a Gathered requirements with the tag JJ NNS. The other one is that, Gathered has never been seen in the training model and system is returning wrong.

Comment: Another paper that I think will be useful for you is https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1603%26context%3Dcis_reports&ved=0ahUKEwjNoa7Z-bvRAhUkBMAKHcwDAtQQFggsMAM&usg=AFQjCNEj7TVxgYsATympvogjc7H3Lnbr1w&sig2=KOu027mHMNF_WeNTNV2YOw . Read it with an emphasize on page 15 (20 of the pdf).